# Understanding AI through a complexity function

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, computability, kolmogorov-complexity

I've been trying to understand in light of a few apparent paradoxes for me. It appears reasonable that we could prove any mathematical problem that has a well defined answer can be solved by a mathematician (or group) given enough time. Yet, this is known to be false due to the existence of the halting problem (and other undecidable series of problems): any mathematician with unlimited time and paper is not guaranteed to be able to prove whether a problem halts.

> **1.** Are the interesting problems that we *do solve* part of an infinite class $P_D$ of decidable problems? (or are we bound to only be able to solve finitely many "interesting" problems?)

Alternatively, I think this may be phrased as

> **1b**. What is the largest known class $P_{max}$ of decidable problems?

I've been trying to put **1b** in more rigorous terms. Define a *partial halting solver* as a program that outputs $1$ if it finds a proof that an input halts, $0$ if it proves that it does not halt and $2$ if it is unsure.

We might seek the best of this partial solvers, ordered defined by some metric:

$$M(P) = \liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}{D_i}$$

Where $D_i = 1$ if input $i$ yields output $0$ or $1$ by some program $P$.

Indeed we easily can see there must exist a program with positive $M$. For example, all programs with the following prefix don't halt (assume without loss of generality that it uses the C language):

- for(i=1;i!=0;i++){}

Since this prefix has $19$ characters $c \in [0,255]$, we know that at least $1$ every $256^{19}$ program of length greater than $19$ will be known not to halt, hence $\max\limits_P{M} \ge \frac{1}{256^{19}}$.

Is there a known bound on $M$, giving $P_{max}$?

I welcome any references that would help me understand those questions better.

Comment: C is a bad language to use in your example: the behaviour of the C fragment you give depends on how you declared $i$. If you declared it to be unsigned, then C guarantees that the loop will terminate. If you declared it to be signed, the behaviour is undefined (but with default settings  most compilers will do wrap-round arithmetic and it will terminate). If you defined it to be a floating point type, then the behaviour is undefined, but it is likely either not to terminate or result in some kind of run-time error with most compilers.

Comment: OK so `for(i=1;;i++){}` in C, or `while 1: pass` in Python.

Comment: @BrianO: are you asking about the C semantics? The answer is that the behaviour is undefined. The python example is guaranteed not to terminate as is while(1){} or for(unsigned i = 1; ; i++){}  in C.

Comment: @Real: More seriously, the distinction between your "partial halting solver" and the programs it analyses isn't very clear from your description of $M(P)$. Is $P$ the solver or the program under analysis?

Comment: I have to point out that yes, there is a largest, infinite class of decidable problems, called... the decidable problems. Or *decidable sets* (of integers, or finite strings on an alphabet—they're equivalent). Problems are Identified with sets via typical codings. A set is *decidable* (or *recursive*) iff there's an algorithm which on every input answers the question "is the input in the set?", responding yes or no in finite time and always terminating. The decidable sets are included in the semi-decidable (aka recursively enumerable) sets, which comprise anything you can write a program for.

Comment: @BrianO: yes that's a great answer to the question up to but not including the bit about partial halting solvers, where the OP seems to be interested in a more specialised question. The question needs more clarification.

Comment: @RobArthan Merci. It's a humble comment & not an answer as I didn't have much/anything to offer about the latter part. Which, yes, is suggestive and interesting... but all I could do was mutter "hmm, reminds me of Kolmogorov complexity".

Comment: @BrianO: sorry, I didn't mean to sound disparaging about your excellent comment. I was really hoping to encourage the OP to clarify the latter part of the question.

Comment: @RobArthan Not to worry, I didn't take it that way. I would only encourage OP to sharpen the question or something/anything, as I too think there's some substance there. It looks promising.